# Highcharts annotations text to print in graph

Tags: highcharts

we would like the text in the bottom of the graph to appear on the graph when we download or print it. We are using the download possibilities that Highcharts gives. 
We want the graph to look like this in this image (with the text in black that appears at the bottom that says European pulp & paper...):
[image]

The problem is that when we download the graph as a jpg, png, pdf or even just print it, the text does not appear. Is there a way to include this text? TIA

Comment: If the text is not part of the chart upon creation but you want it on export you can use the `exportChart` to do so. We use this to add footer text to charts on export using the `subtitle` text.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set additional options for the exported chart via [exporting.chartOptions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.chartOptions). Additional text can be set as subtitle - see available options in [API Docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/subtitle).

```
exporting: {
 chartOptions: {
      chart: {
        spacingBottom: 90
      },
      subtitle: {
        verticalAlign: 'bottom',
        text: `Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.`
      }
    }
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/b231fz7c/

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help!

Comment: this fiddle example does not render the exporting chartOptions when printing. Just when exporting/downloading PNG, JPEG, PDF, or SVG.  https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/exporting.chartOptions

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54365577/1893251 for how to modify the chart when printing.